# Processing Excel or CSV file uploaded by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am writing a ruby on rails application. As a part of that I need to implement a facility to upload the excel, csv or excelx file. I think, it can be done by paperclip. But I need to process the file later i.e. I want to store the contents of the file in my db. But I did not find anything related to how to process the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the roo gem for processing CSV and various spreadsheet formats including Excel, OpenOffice and Google.

There is a railscast that covers this [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) without needing a file upload gem.

You may also want to consider a Rack based file handing gem like Carrierwave which has good support for post upload processing.

Depending on your load and the reliability you require you may even want to defer processing to a background job using the very good resque gem with Redis as a very reliable and fast queuing server. Besides reliable queuing, Redis also functions as an awesome cache server (much better than Memcached IMO).

Answer (score -2):

you can use this documentation for paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip 
it shows how u can upload a document.

Comment: that documentation is rather large in scope, it would have been nice to link to the specific spot in the documentation not just the github project page.